# regex matches wrong

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling with a problem in `RegExp`.
I have this Regex:

```
\b(.*)\n*\s*\((\n*\s*.*\n*\s*)\)\n*\s*;
```

to Match a function calling for Example:

```
print("Hello World!");
```

But when I have several calls in each line it have a weird output

Regex => [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/o55aj1/1)

I hope Someone can help me.

Comment: Use the single line or multi line flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this output?

```
say"hello World"
say"hello World 1"
say"hello World 2"
say"hello World 3"
```

You can try this regex for capturing what you want.

```
\b(.*?)\(([^)]*)\)\s*;\s*\n?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o55aj1/3),,, in which the function name `say` is captured to `group 1` (or `\1`) and function argument string inside parenthesis is captured to `group 2` (or `\2`).

Replace matches with `\1\2\n`, then results in such output.

Comment: Thanks . That is exactly what i wanted to get.♥